# Android app Google Play Billing: onConsumeResponse: 0 ,how to overcome?

Tags: token, android-billing

**Problem statement:**

In my app using Google Play Billing V5.2.0, the billing screen showed "Purchase successful" message after clicking buy-button for consumable product. However, my codes did not receive "OK" response code to execute in-app entitlement to user. So, I logged the onConsumeResponse code to check what code responded by billing server, it was "0" that represents "OK" which means a success. How can I overcome this issue? Or what mistake did I make?

**Log:**

```
I/onConsumeResponse: onConsumeResponse: 0
```

**Code:**

```
ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsumeResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull String purchaseToken) {
                Log.i("onConsumeResponse", "purchaseToken: "+ purchaseToken);
                Log.i("onConsumeResponse", "onConsumeResponse: "+ billingResult.getResponseCode()+ " " + billingResult.getDebugMessage());
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                    //Handle success of consume operation: grant coins
                    grantCoins(purchase.getProducts());
                    billingClient.endConnection();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(BillingActivity.this, "Product consumed successfully, restart app to see changes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(BillingActivity.this, "Product consume error, please contact developer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```